# How to Integrate fingerprint scanner in Java web application

Tags: java, fingerprint

I am fresher and I want to use fingerprint facility in my web application. I tried neurotechnology API but that API give me an error that no scanner found. Demo application which is given by device manufacturer is working successfully but not my application.

So please suggest me which API is useful and easy API to integrate fingerprint scanner in my application.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is classified as off topic because it's asking for a software recommendation.

Comment: I am asking about software recommendation I want solution on my problem and Problem is how to integrate Fingerprint scanner in my web Application?

Comment: You can http://camsunit.com/application/html-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html if it helps. This gives API to connect the fingerprint scanner from the javascript program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not worked on it but by doing google and access some other resources i have found one source which will provide you fingerprint scanner api, please try it and also let me know if it is working fine.
Here is the link:- [griaulebiometrics](http://www.griaulebiometrics.com/)

Comment: I will provide you response very soon it my pleasure so +1 for this good answer.